# What is Active Directory and Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services & When to use?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, active-directory

hello i am a bit confuse about active directory (AD) and active directory lightweight directory services (AD LDS), basically i want to build an application and i want to integrate it with directory services to authenticate users account, but i really have no idea what and when to use? and what is the difference? is it possible to use AD LDS in local computer without joining a domain? thanks in advance.

NOTE : i am using visual studio 2012 to build my app, and my computer does not belong to any domain.

Comment: This tutorial is very good: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OTpbQkW3kj4&list=PLBBA04BF566F0E0D6 if you want to have a better understanding about Active Directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think that an answer for your question exists somewhere in [Microsoft documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754361%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Active-Directory is a bit more more than a common LDAP Directory like OpenLDAP or Oracle Directory Server Enterprise Edition (formerly SUN Directory Server Enterprise Edition). It's a "**System** Directory". The main difference with a simple Directory is that it's built in with a Microsoft specific "Schema" and a security infrastructure with "Kerberos". So installing AD is the same as promoting a server in a "Domain controler". In other words you can use the AD for your own usage, but his first usage is for the "System" (Domain) security.

ADLDS is the most recent name for an old product called ADAM (Active Directory Application Mode). As you can guess, this Directory can be created just for the usage of your own application, you can build the Schema you want, you can install it on a Worksation or a server, it exists version that you can redistribute with your own application.